# how many solutions $f(x)=0$ has over an interval given derivative graph

Tags: calculus

The equation $f(x)=0$ can have no more than two solutions on the interval $[-3,3]$. Explain why. I was given the graph of the derivative with this question, and it looked like $\arctan x$ over $(-3,3)$.

Comment: Can you draw a function with say, three zeros? What can you say about the derivative? Did you perhaps just learn something called the mean value theorem?

Comment: Well, my teacher just gave it to us and didn't teach us the theorem. I searched it up but I am not sure how to apply it.

Comment: Echoing what @qbert mentioned, suppose (by way of contradiction) that $f(x)$ had $3$ or more distinct zeros on $[-3,4]$. What does the mean value theorem, or even Rolle's Theorem, tell you about the number of zeros that it's derivative has? How many zeros does its derivative actually have?

Comment: The derivative has one zero judging by the graph. However, I don't have the equation, so I don't think I can use MVT.

Comment: I can't see the graph, but how many times do you see the derivative (i.e. the slope of the function) changing sign? Is it just once? If the derivative goes from positive to negative (or vice-versa) only once, you cannot have the function cross the x-axis more than twice (i.e. no more than two solutions). Of course, it is possible to have fewer than two solutions.

Comment: Oh, ok. I initially thought that, but wasn't sure. Thank you for clearing it up.

Comment: If the derivative is null on an interval (more than one point) it is possible that your function has a flat portion. (eg [Image](https://imgur.com/a/FfPuu7h)) and thus $f(x) = 0$ has an infinite number of solutions